# WCF Method is returning xml fragment but no xml UTF-8 header

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

My method does not return the  header, just the root element xml.

```
internal Message CreateReturnMessage(string output, string contentType)
            {
                // create dictionaryReader for the Message
                byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
                XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(resultBytes, 0, resultBytes.Length, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null);

                if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
                    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = contentType;

                // create Message
                return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "", xdr);
            }
```

However, the output I get is:

```
<Test>
   <Message>Hello World!</Message> 
</Test>
```

I would like the output to render as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Test>
   <Message>Hello World!</Message> 
</Test>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this URL http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wifry/archive/2007/05/15/wcf-bodywriter-and-raw-xml-problems.aspx
Pass the xml string to the custom bodywriter and it will output xml declaration

Answer (score 0):

so assuming `output` param is coming in as...

```
<Test>
   <Message>Hello World!</Message> 
</Test>
```

What do you expect to happen? You aren't writing xml, just reading the `output` string through a reader. The reader class won't add anything to your fragment, it's a reader, not a writer.

You could so something like this instead...It will parse your output as xml and then you can add a declaration before giving it to the message.

```
var output = "<Test><Message>Hello World!</Message></Test>";
var xd = XDocument.Parse(output);
xd.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
return Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, xd.ToString());
```

Comment: I'm building up the xml using XDocument and returning the result using the method below:


[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/result.xml")]
Message GetResult();


class method:
public Message GetResult()
{
     var output = "<Test><Message>Hello World!</Message></Test>";
     return CreateReturnMessage(output, "text/xml")
}

Already tried adding XDeclaration but output appears as below:

<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><Test> <Message>Hello World!</Message> </Test></string>